# Insert string with comma into varchar?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to insert a string that contains a comma into a varchar in vb.net. How do I make the insert statement I'm building understand that I want "X,Y" to be in the varchar and not X in the varchar and Y in the next column?

Comment: Please supply sample SQL INSERT code

Comment: From what I read your code is an easy [SQL-injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) target.

Comment: Not really, as theres no interface for an SQL-injection attack to occur on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use parametised queries:

```
Dim cmd as new sqlcommand("INSERT INTO TableA (ColA) VALUES (@ColA)", Conn)
cmd.parameters.add("@ColA",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = "X,Y"
cmd.executenonquery()
```